# ¿Como hacer que los datos de mi formulario lleguen al correo destinario?

Tags: php, html5, formularios, email

Buenas noches actualmente estoy apoyando a un amigo a realizar un sitio web, y lo acepte sin tener tanta experencia en el lenguaje php, el problema que tengo es el siguiente: en la pagina web en la cual estoy apoyando, realice un formulario, pero al momento de enviar los datos del formulario al correo destinario administrador2@gmail.com, no le llega nada ni en bandeja principal y ni como spam. Recalco que al momento de llenar el formulario, me dice que el mensaje fue enviado.

<----- Codigo del formulario contacto --->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <?php require_once 'includes/all_scripts.php'; ?>
        
        <title>Contáctanos, Proyecto Ecológico</title>
        <meta name="Description" content="Ponte en contacto con nosotros y busquemos juntos la mejor alternativa de inversión para tu descanso" />
        <meta name="Keywords" content="terrenos ecologicos," />
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php require_once 'includes/header.php'; ?>

        <section id="wrapper_contacto">
            <img src="imagenes/contacto.png" alt="Contáctanos Reserva" class="cont_us" />

            <section id="frmContacto">
                <form  name="frm_Contactanos" id="frm_Contactanos">
                    
                    <input type="text" name="txtNombre" id="txtNombre" value="Nombre:" class="validar" />

                    <input type="text" name="txtTel" id="txtTel" value="Teléfono:" class="validar" />

                    <input type="text" name="txtMail" id="txtMail" value="E-mail:" class="validar" />

                    <textarea name="txtComentarios" id="txtComentarios">Comentarios</textarea>
                    <div class="clear"></div>

                    <img src="imagenes/enviar.png" id="send" class="send" alt="Tulum" />
                </form>
                <div id="mensaje">
                    <img src="imagenes/loading.gif" style="position: absolute;right: 100px;top: -38px;" />
                    <p>prueba del mensaje</p>
                </div>
            </section>

            <img src="imagenes/pajaro.png" alt="Terrenos ecológicos" class="bird" />
        </section>
        <div class="clear"></div>

        <?php require_once 'includes/footer.php'; ?>
```

<------ Codigo php del correo destinatario --->

```
<?
//include("scripts/mysql.php");

$nombre = $_REQUEST["txtNombre"];
$telefono = $_REQUEST["txtTel"];
$email = $_REQUEST["txtMail"];

$destinatario = "admnistrador2@gmail.com\r\n";

//Enviar el correo
$asunto = "Se ha generado un nuevo prospecto"; 
$cuerpo = ' 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Nuevo prospecto</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<h1>Se ha generado un nuevo prospecto</h1> 
<br /><br /><b>Nombre: </b>'.$nombre.'
<br /><b>Teléfono: </b>'.$telefono.'
<br /><b>Email: </b>'.$email.'
<br /><b>Comentarios: </b>'.$_REQUEST["txtComentarios"].'
<br /><br /><h2>Suerte!!!</h2>
</body> 
</html>'; 

//Envío en formato HTML 
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"; 

//Dirección del remitente 
$headers .= "From: Notificaciones Inbound <programacion@reservamikil.com>\r\n"; 
 
//direcciones que recibián copia 
$headers .= "Cc: administrador1@gmail.com\r\n";
 
//Direcciones que recibirán copia oculta 
$headers .= "Bcc: reserva@hotmail.com\r\n"; 

mail($destinatario,$asunto,$cuerpo,$headers);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar con PHPMailer

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Baja la librería y creas un archivo Ejemplo: send.php

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

//Datos pasados por POST ...
$var1 = $_POST["txtName"];

$mensaje = "PUEDES PONER CODIGO HTML AQUÍ";

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "correoEmisor@ejemplo.com";
$mail->Password = "contraseñaCorreo";
$mail->setFrom("correoEmisor@ejemplo.com", "Nombre de Correo");

$mail->addAddress("correoDestinatario@ejemplo.com");

$mail->Subject = "SUJETO";
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('message.html'), __DIR__);
$mail->Body = "$mensaje";
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}else{
    echo 'Message sent!';
}
```

Comment: Gracias por el dato, lo aplicare.